# How do I convert a string date to date-only format?

Tags: python

I have searched previous questions and seen potential solutions to my problem but or some reason I the solutions won't work for me.

I have a variable `referencePeriodStartDate` which is a date in string format.

```
referencePeriodStartDate = "01/01/2017"
```

I am trying to convert to a date only format and have tried:

```
import datetime

referencePeriodStartDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(referencePeriodStartDate , '%d-%m-%y')
```

But cannot get the date returned in a date format. (the code just ends)

Comment: Did you notice that the string you are trying to parse has the format DD/MM/YYYY but the `strptime` argument gives you DD-MM-YY?

Comment: And if you want a `date` object rather than `datetime`, use `datetime.date` rather than `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your supplied datestring is `"01/01/2017"`

but you're telling strptime it looks like `(referencePeriodStartDate , '%d-%m-%y')`

The format needs to match exactly. Either change `"01/01/2017"` to `"01-01-2017"` or `(referencePeriodStartDate , '%d-%m-%y')` to `(referencePeriodStartDate , '%d/%m/%y')`

edit: also `%Y` is for year and century while `%y` is for two digit year. Read more here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html

Comment: yep just noticed that, was about to edit

Comment: thanks guys, but still not working. I am now am trying  referencePeriodStartDate = datetime.date(referencePeriodStartDate, '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: @Stacey https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/025d1db7-4bac-4408-9f75-9bc9727f6c24/?i=true it works for me

Comment: Awesome, I can't see the difference that fixed it, many thanks!